# Selenium Scroll Wait

Tags: php, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I can not understand why only part of the links are returned without `sleep(1);` function. Although the script works synchronously and after `$web_driver->executeScript` the object is already loaded, all links have already been loaded.

```
 <?php

  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
  use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
  use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

  $caps = array("platform"=>"SIERRA", "browserName" => "chrome", "version" => "69");
  $web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
    "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    $caps
  );
  $web_driver->get("https://winestyle.ru/wine/gerard-bertrand/");

  $web_driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);');
  sleep(1);

  $element = $web_driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector(".bg-text[title='Артикул']"));
  foreach ($element as $e){
    echo $e->getText().'<br>';
  }

  $web_driver->quit();
?>
```

return without sleep:

Артикул:в101222
Артикул:в99863
Артикул:в99981
Артикул:в101225
Артикул:в101212
Артикул:в101224
Артикул:в101211
Артикул:в92722
Артикул:в92723
Артикул:в101208
Артикул:в101210
Артикул:в99979
Артикул:в101223
Артикул:в101220
Артикул:в101213
Артикул:в101221
Артикул:в101227
Артикул:в101218
Артикул:в101217
Артикул:в101215

return with sleep:

Артикул:в101222
Артикул:в99863
Артикул:в99981
Артикул:в101225
Артикул:в101212
Артикул:в101224
Артикул:в101211
Артикул:в92722
Артикул:в92723
Артикул:в101208
Артикул:в101210
Артикул:в99979
Артикул:в101223
Артикул:в101220
Артикул:в101213
Артикул:в101221
Артикул:в101227
Артикул:в101218
Артикул:в101217
Артикул:в101215
Артикул:в101226
Артикул:в99980
Артикул:в85254
Артикул:в66382
Артикул:в66386
Артикул:в66387
Артикул:в85253
Артикул:в101214
Артикул:в101219

Comment: You should also explain what is the issue here, what is happening and what was expected and what you tried already to fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the page has implemented lazy loading - any extra information - new elements, are request through ajax only when the user scrolls to the end of the page.

And this is what's happening in your script - you've executed the js to scroll to the end. If you at that moment execute `findElements` without the sleep, the page would not have time to send the ajax request, wait for an parse the respone, and update the DOM. Thus you will get only the currently present elements.

With the `sleep` you give it that possibility.

Have in mind the hardcoded value 1s may sometimes work, and sometimes - not; if the backend takes more time to generate the response, or the network is slow - new data may not be received in time.

An alternative solution would be to poll the DOM for the number of target elements every X milliseconds, and continue once that number increases. This though must accommodate for the case where there are no more results (no more артикулы Russian? артикули Bulgarian? :), and to break out of the polling loop (could be done if there's a total results counter on the page, or similar).